# Why (referenceTos[0] != null) check is being performed in following code?

Tags: java, salesforce

I was going through a salesforce.com developer documentation

[code link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm)

In this part of code why (referenceTos[0] != null) check is being performed?

```
        // Determine whether this is a reference field
        if (field.getType() == FieldType.reference)
        {                            
            // Determine whether this field refers to another object
            String[] referenceTos = field.getReferenceTo();
            if (referenceTos != null && referenceTos[0] != null)
            {
                System.out.println("\t\tField references the following objects:");
                for (int k = 0; k < referenceTos.length; k++)
                {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t" + referenceTos[k]);
                }
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A java array can hold 0 elements.**

Because `referenceTos[0]` check there because some times it may not be `null`,but its empty.

Comment: The question is why, not when.

Answer (score 0):

To determine there is at least one value in the array. Since the array is probably filled starting from index 0, having a non-null value there means the array contains at least one value. If the value of index 0 would be null, this would mean the array is empty and there's no need for the next piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is they do not want to print `Field references the following objects:` thing if null is coming. `referenceTos != null` does not mean the elements are not null, it just means array itself is not null.

If you were remove that condition, U may end up getting(without for each looped):

```
Field references the following objects:
```

That is why it is there, to check not null array's 1st element is not null.